# Delphi TPageControl trouble in dll

Tags: delphi, dll

I am coding up a VST plugin dll.  I have no trouble with the plugin until I use a PageControl and place controls on it.

Specifically, my dll seems to have trouble receiving mouse clicks if the control I click on is in a tabsheet, and has code to execute in a mouse onclick or onChange event. However, this ONLY occurs when the hosting program gives control back to my plugin. I can interact perfectly fine with the plugin before the hosting program implements the settings I select, but once it tries to hand back control, I can only click on, seemingly, any control that does not implement any written mouse event code (Tlabel clicks are fine, tabsheet changes are fine too).

The plugin works fine as long as I don't try to make changes to the settings through the controls after the hosting program hands back control to the dll. I can use the same settings over and over again with no problem. I can change them as much as I want until I let the hosting program implement the plugin values (which works perfectly).

This is really tricky to debug since the program is in a dll.

I have tried using Delphi XE2 and Delphi 2009.

Any clues?

Comment: I think you'll need to do some more debugging to gather some more info

Comment: Debugging a DLL (developed in Delphi) is very simple

Comment: You might need to expand on what "gives control back" means, because the problem seems to be there.  What does it do? How does it take control in the first place? If you can show some code that would also be really helpful.

Comment: The hosting application provides a way to 'start' using the the dll to handle the audio data. Some just implement in real time, but DAW's will handover the data to the dll, and then when the dll is finished it takes back control.